# Prove that a bijection exists

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Prove that there is a bijection $f: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$f(x,y) = h(g(x) + r(y))$

As far as I understand, one need to prove that there exist such $g(x)$ and $r(y)$ so for any $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2) \Rightarrow g(x_1) + r(y_1) \neq g(x_2) + r(y_2)$.

Is there any way to prove that such functions exist or is there another convenient way to solve the problem?

Comment: Who's $h$, $g$ and $r$?

Comment: The domain of $g$ and $r$ is $\mathbb{R}$ and their values are real numbers. $h$ should be a bijection from whatever $g + r$ gives to $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

You may create a number alternating the digits of $x$ and $y$.
(This is not the full answer and it has some problems, but it might help you get started.)

---

**Edit:**

Since the answer is already accepted, I will post an example for $h$, $g$ and $r$.

Initially, I though about alternating digits, but negative numbers might be a problem. So, using the exponential function (that is injective) will allow to get positive numbers. Afterwards, we could alternate the digits between the transformed numbers.

Let $a_k \in \{0,1,\ldots,9\}$ be the decimal representation of $e^x$, i. e.:
$$
e^x = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} a_k 10^k
$$
with $a_k$ chosen such that for any $J$ there exists at least one $j > J$ such that $a_j \neq 9$. (Thanks due to [fleablood](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/280126), this way we prevent two sequences giving the same number.)

The function $g(x)$ will be defined as:
$$
g(x) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} a_k 10^{2k}
$$
Note the exponent $2k$.

Similarly, let $b_k \in \{0,1,\ldots,9\}$ be the decimal representation of $e^y$, i. e.:
$$
e^y = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} b_k 10^k
$$
with $b_k$ chosen such that for any $J$ there exists at least one $j > J$ such that $b_j \neq 9$.

The function $r(x)$ will be defined as:
$$
r(x) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} b_k 10^{2k+1}
$$
Note the exponent $2k+1$.

And the function $h$ can be simply:
$$
h(z) = \log z
$$

This way, the sum between $g$ and $r$ will give a positive number with alternating digits of $e^x$ and $e^y$. Since $h$ is the logarithm function, the outcome can be either positive or negative or zero.

Comment: If you specify no infinite trailing $9$s, I don't see any problems.  $x= \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}a_{x,k}*10^k$ is a uniques decimal rep and same for $y= \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}a_{y,k}*10^k$ then $f(x,y) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}a_{x,k}*10^{2k} + \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}a_{x,y}*10^{2k+1}$ doesn't have many problems at all that I can see.

Comment: @fleablood That was exactly my idea.

Comment: I know.  I was following through on *your* idea.  You said "it has some problems" but I don't think it does.  You need to specifically point out trailing 9s are not allowed so that every real number has unique representation. but other than that, I don't so any problem.... Oh I suppose binary representation may be easier.

Comment: On my first approach, I stumbled upon the negative numbers, but then I remembered of using exponentials. Regarding the decomposition, any base will do. I'll edit my answer later to include the full description of the functions.